# What are push configurations (host, port, username, password) for TextSecure Server

Tags: android, push-notification, jersey, google-cloud-messaging

I installed TextSecure Server.(https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure-Server)

I also modified some server side code to to simplify registration process and to accept predefined sms/voice verification code.

I also created custom TextSecure app with my own TextSecure server details. And installed on my two android devices.
I successfully registered TextSecure app on my two mobiles. No problem at all.

But when I send message from one mobile, server gets this message, but not able to connect to GCM push framework, and send this message to another mobile as a SMS. The message contents are in encrypted form.
I don't understand what are gcm push frameworks credentials (host, port, username, password) that I need to mention in yml configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

You also need the PushServer: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/PushServer

The push configuration (host, port, username, password) is needed to communicate with the PushServer. The PushServer communicates with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). You can configure GCM in the local.yml file for the PushServer (senderId and apiKey). You will need a Google Developer Account for that.

Hope this helps!