# TextSecure (Signal) open source server setup

Tags: java, android, maven, multiuserchat

I am trying to setup text-secure server, but i couldn't find a proper guide or documentation on it, i have built textsecure - server jar and client side apk from the open source source available in GitHub, but how to configure it and use our own server for hosting the same. I coudnt find any resources on the same.

As per my understanding, **i have built the following using maven**:

1.Websocket-Resources.jar (dependency jar)
2.TextSecureServer.jar

*Other similar jars provided in github (are they needed too?):*
libtextsecure-java
libaxolotl-java

in the *sample.yml* file in *Textsecure-server/config* path, it is asking for twilio,gcm push & database credentials.

w.r.t twilio and push, i have idea, but w.r.t database, should we use the same postgre or textsecure is compatible with any DB.

My Questions:

Are there any other dependencies apart from the push-server for GCM to textsecure?

How to host the textsecure in our own server by configuring our server ip and port?

***If anyone has configured textsecure successfully,Kindly provide us an insight into its setup.***

Reference link:

[What are push configurations (host, port, username, password) for TextSecure Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109437/what-are-push-configurations-host-port-username-password-for-textsecure-ser)

Comment: have you congifured it? i need help. i have errors during installation of PushServer.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully started TextSecure server. I've explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699970/run-custom-textsecure-signal-server/34471995#34471995). For RedPhone features you can check [this](https://github.com/skal1ozz/RedPhoneServer) repo.

Q: Are there any other dependencies apart from the push-server for GCM to textsecure?

A: Yes, without hack /api/ url you can't reg your phone in the database, you need to setup RedPhone part or you can just return http200 for this request if you going to use only text.

Q: How to host the textsecure in our own server by configuring our server ip and port?

A: You need to setup frontend proxy for textsecure backend. After that you need to edit your credentials in client app.